# Ember Data: How to call DS.RESTAdapter's "findMany" manually?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I use Ember Data's `DS.RESTAdapter` successfully. That adapter has a method named [`findMany`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L285).

<sub>That method is used behind-the-scenes whenever some model instance's `hasMany` relationship is accessed: `findMany` takes the set of bare IDs already existing in the relationship to query the remote server for the full-blown data for all of those IDs [in one bulk AJAX request-response](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_relationships).</sub>

In my Ember app, I now have the requirement to query for a set of IDs **manually**. The app obtains these IDs from somewhere else, outside of any Ember Data model instance's relationship.

<sub>If it helps to visualize this requirement, imagine a user that types in a comma-separated list of IDs to have Ember Data take care of finding those IDs by querying the remote server, then Ember Data adding the returned data to some model instance's relationship.</sub>

Therefore: how can I bulk-query for a set of IDs, preferably leveraging `DS.RESTAdapter.findMany`, then add the returned Ember Data instances to some model instance's relationships?

**TL;DR**: I'm looking for something like `App.MyModelType.**findMany**(234, 583, 234)`, but I don't want to loop over `App.MyModelType.find` as this isn't efficient for a large number of IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Ember Data versions dating pre 2013-06-25, add the following code to your `app.js` before the definition of any Ember Data model classes:

```
DS.Model.reopenClass({
    findMany: function(ids) {
        //taken from model.js's storeAlias(..)

        var store = Ember.get(DS, 'defaultStore'),
            args = [].slice.call(arguments);

        args.unshift(this);
        Ember.assert("Your application does not have a 'Store' property defined. Attempts to call 'findMany' on model classes will fail. Please provide one as with 'YourAppName.Store = DS.Store.extend()'", !!store);

        return store["findMany"].apply(store, args);
    }
});

//begin definition of App.MyModelType = DS.Model.extend({..}); here
```

<sub>`store.findMany(..)` will determine which IDs don't have a loaded record in the store yet.
For these unloaded records, `store.findMany(..)` will call `store.fetchMany(..)`.

`store.fetchMany(..)` will use `adapter.findMany(..)` to delegate the finding logic to the used `DS.Adapter` implementation.</sub>

With above adition of `findMany` to the `DS.Model` supertype, you can now use `App.MyModelType.findMany(..)` and get returned an array of model instances, for example

```
var someArrayWithIds = [1, 2, 3];
someModelInstances = App.MyModelType.findMany(someArrayWithIds);
```